# Factor loading and corrected item to factor correlation

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis

By definitions seems that both factor loading and corrected item to factor correlation (statistic when calculating Cronbach's alpha) essentially indicate to the same - the correlation of the item with the respective factor, but I get different scores in SPSS on both indicators, therefore presume there are more mathematically sound and grounded explanations of how these differ. Could please someone reason how they differ, as from definitions I got confused that they are kind of the same...
PS: used orthogonal rotation in factor analysis.

Comment: This is too vague. Please explain in details what you did in factor analysis and what you did in reliability analysis, what output you then try to link between the two.

Comment: I did factor analysis with varimax rotation and I report their loadings, as well as did reliability analysis and report corrected item to factor correlation (Cronbach's alpha for each of identified factors). From definitions of what the loading is and what the corrected item to factor correlation is it seems that it is kind of the same, but in that case I do not get the same scores. How could I better explain my question? What other info should I provide?

Comment: E.g. factor loadings on the factor structure matrix indicate the correlation between the particular item and the factor that the item belongs.

Comment: Item-to total factor correlation as I understand also explains the correlation of particular item with the factor. Should then these 2 indicators be of the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write "item-to-total factor correlation" I believe you should remove the word "factor."  Then you will have the term usually used as part of Cronbach's alpha reliability analysis to denote the correlation between one item and the sum of all other items under consideration.  No latent factor is created or computed as part of this relatively simple procedure.  In contrast, a factor loading comes out of more complicated computations from factor analysis that do create a latent factor presumed to be underlying the scores on the various individual items. So the item-total correlations and the factor loadings will differ.